# Java Draw Arc Between 2 Points

Tags: java, trigonometry, graphics2d

I'm having trouble drawing the smallest arc described by 3 points: the arc center, an "anchored" end point, and a second point that gives the other end of the arc by determining a radius.  I used the law of cosines to determine the length of the arc and tried using atan for the starting degree, but the starting position for the arc is off.

I managed to get the arc to lock onto the anchor point (x1,y1) when it's in Quadrant 2, but that will only work when it is in Quadrant 2.

Solutions I can see all have a bunch of if-statements to determine the location of the 2 points relative to each other, but I'm curious if I'm overlooking something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

class Canvas extends JComponent {
    float circleX, circleY, x1, y1, x2, y2, dx, dy, dx2, dy2, radius, radius2;
    Random random = new Random();

    public Canvas() {

        //Setup. 

        x1 = random.nextInt(250);
        y1 = random.nextInt(250);

        //Cant have x2 == circleX
        while (x1 == 150 || y1 == 150)
        {
            x1 = random.nextInt(250);
            y1 = random.nextInt(250);
        }

        circleX = 150; //circle center is always dead center.
        circleY = 150;


        //Radius between the 2 points must be equal.
        dx = Math.abs(circleX-x1);
        dy = Math.abs(circleY-y1);

        //c^2 = a^2 + b^2 to solve for the radius
        radius = (float) Math.sqrt((float)Math.pow(dx, 2) + (float)Math.pow(dy, 2));

        //2nd random point
        x2 = random.nextInt(250);
        y2 = random.nextInt(250);

        //I need to push it out to radius length, because the radius is equal for both points.
        dx2 = Math.abs(circleX-x2);
        dy2 = Math.abs(circleY-y2);
        radius2 = (float) Math.sqrt((float)Math.pow(dx2, 2) + (float)Math.pow(dy2, 2));

        dx2 *= radius/radius2;
        dy2 *= radius/radius2;

        y2 = circleY+dy2;
        x2 = circleX+dx2;
        //Radius now equal for both points.
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g2) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g2;
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL));

        Arc2D.Float centerPoint = new Arc2D.Float(150-2,150-2,4,4, 0, 360, Arc2D.OPEN);
        Arc2D.Float point1 = new Arc2D.Float(x1-2, y1-2, 4, 4, 0, 360, Arc2D.OPEN);
        Arc2D.Float point2 = new Arc2D.Float(x2-2, y2-2, 4, 4, 0, 360, Arc2D.OPEN);

        //3 points drawn in black
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.draw(centerPoint);
        g.draw(point1);
        g.draw(point2);

        float start = 0;
        float distance;

        //Form a right triangle to find the length of the hypotenuse.
        distance = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(x2-x1),2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(y2-y1), 2));

        //Law of cosines to determine the internal angle between the 2 points.
        distance = (float) (Math.acos(((radius*radius) + (radius*radius) - (distance*distance)) / (2*radius*radius)) * 180/Math.PI);

        float deltaY = circleY - y1;
        float deltaX = circleX - x1;

        float deltaY2 = circleY - y2;
        float deltaX2 = circleX - x2;

        float angleInDegrees = (float) ((float) Math.atan((float) (deltaY / deltaX)) * 180 / Math.PI);
        float angleInDegrees2 = (float) ((float) Math.atan((float) (deltaY2 / deltaX2)) * 180 / Math.PI);

        start = angleInDegrees;

        //Q2 works.
        if (x1 < circleX)
        {
            if (y1 < circleY)
            {
                start*=-1;
                start+=180;
            } else if (y2 > circleX) {
                start+=180;
                start+=distance;
            }
        }

        //System.out.println("Start: " + start);
        //Arc drawn in blue
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Arc2D.Float arc = new Arc2D.Float(circleX-radius,  //Center x 
                                          circleY-radius,  //Center y Rotates around this point.
                                          radius*2,
                                          radius*2,
                                          start, //start degree
                                          distance, //distance to travel
                                          Arc2D.OPEN); //Type of arc.
        g.draw(arc);
    }
}

public class Angle implements MouseListener {

    Canvas view;
    JFrame window;

    public Angle() {
        window = new JFrame();
        view = new Canvas();
        view.addMouseListener(this);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setBounds(30, 30, 400, 400);
        window.getContentPane().add(view);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        new Angle();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        window.getContentPane().remove(view);
        view = new Canvas();
        window.getContentPane().add(view);
        view.addMouseListener(this);
        view.revalidate();
        view.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question; are you asking what the arc length is for two points on a circle's circumference, given an arbitrary center point?

Comment: No. I'm asking how to draw the smallest arc between the 2 points, given the center of a circle and 2 points that lie on the circle. I'm really looking for the starting point -- where to start drawing the arc, and whether I should switch the orientation of the arc (clockwise / counterclockwise).

Comment: I'm still working on it -- it looks remarkably simple at first glance, but then remarkably complicated on further review, but I can't shake the feeling that ultimately it is in fact fairly simple. Anyway, I've identified certain scenarios which would make things tricky. If I can solve them in a generalizable fashion, I may yet have a workable answer.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought when I first looked at it, but my almost-working solution turned into many if-statements. I felt as though I was overlooking something. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're having trouble as you say because you're trying to solve an impossible problem.  The center plus two points is too much information.  There is almost never a circular arc with known center that will intersect two arbitrary points simply because each point gives its own radius.  If the radii are different, there is no answer.  If you know the center and one point, then only one additional number determines an arc.  This can be the x- or y-coordinate of the second arc end point or its angle with respect to the center.   If you clarify, I can give you a concise answer.

Comment: @Gene The 2 points lie on the circle, therefore the radii are equal. In my Monte Carlo code, 2 points are drawn: The center of the circle, and 1 point on the circle. From this point, a radius is calculated, and a second point on the circle is generated off of this radius, therefore, the radii are equal. These are the 3 given points: 2 points that lie on a circle, and its center point. I'm having trouble drawing the smallest arc between these 2 points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.  It tests with click and drag to set the two points rather than random numbers.  It's considerably simpler than what you were attempting and other solutions posted so far.

Notes:

- `Math.atan2()` is a friend in problems like this.
- Little helper functions make it easier to reason about your code.
- It's best practice to use instance variables for *independent* values only and compute the dependent values in local variables.
- My code fixes some Swing usage problems like calling Swing functions from the main thread.

Code follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

class TestCanvas extends JComponent {

    float x0 = 150f, y0 = 150f;   // Arc center. Subscript 0 used for center throughout.
    float xa = 200f, ya = 150f;   // Arc anchor point.  Subscript a for anchor.
    float xd = 150f, yd =  50f;   // Point determining arc angle. Subscript d for determiner.

    // Return the distance from any point to the arc center.
    float dist0(float x, float y) {
        return (float)Math.sqrt(sqr(x - x0) + sqr(y - y0));
    }

    // Return polar angle of any point relative to arc center.
    float angle0(float x, float y) {
        return (float)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y0 - y, x - x0));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g0) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g0;

        // Can always draw the center point.
        dot(g, x0, y0);

        // Get radii of anchor and det point.
        float ra = dist0(xa, ya);
        float rd = dist0(xd, yd);

        // If either is zero there's nothing else to draw.
        if (ra == 0 || rd == 0) { return; }

        // Get the angles from center to points.
        float aa = angle0(xa, ya);
        float ad = angle0(xd, yd);  // (xb, yb) would work fine, too.

        // Draw the arc and other dots.
        g.draw(new Arc2D.Float(x0 - ra, y0 - ra, // box upper left
                2 * ra, 2 * ra,                  // box width and height
                aa, angleDiff(aa, ad),           // angle start, extent 
                Arc2D.OPEN));
        dot(g, xa, ya);

        // Use similar triangles to get the second dot location.
        float xb = x0 + (xd - x0) * ra / rd;
        float yb = y0 + (yd - y0) * ra / rd;
        dot(g, xb, yb);
    }

    // Some helper functions.

    // Draw a small dot with the current color.
    static void dot(Graphics2D g, float x, float y) {
        final int rad = 2;
        g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Float(x - rad, y - rad, 2 * rad, 2 * rad));
    }

    // Return the square of a float.
    static float sqr(float x) { return x * x; }

    // Find the angular difference between a and b, -180 <= diff < 180.
    static float angleDiff(float a, float b) {
        float d = b - a;
        while (d >= 180f) { d -= 360f; }
        while (d < -180f) { d += 360f; }
        return d;
    }

    // Construct a test canvas with mouse handling.
    TestCanvas() {
        addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseListener);
    }

    // Listener changes arc parameters with click and drag.
    MouseInputAdapter mouseListener = new MouseInputAdapter() {
        boolean mouseDown = false; // Is left mouse button down?

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                mouseDown = true;
                xa = xd = e.getX();
                ya = yd = e.getY();
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                mouseDown = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (mouseDown) {
                xd = e.getX();
                yd = e.getY();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    };
}

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().add(new TestCanvas());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Swing code must run in the UI thread, so
        // must invoke setVisible rather than just calling it.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. What I took from this was my arcTan calculation was incorrect. My program now works great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
package curve;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        PointF pFrom = new PointF(-10f, 30.0f);
        PointF pTo = new PointF(-100f, 0.0f);
        List<PointF> points = generateCurve(pFrom, pTo, 100f, 7f, true, true);

        System.out.println(points);

        // Calculate the bounds of the curve
        Rectangle2D.Float bounds = new Rectangle2D.Float(points.get(0).x, points.get(0).y, 0, 0);
        for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); ++i) {
            bounds.add(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y);
        }
        bounds.add(pFrom.x, pFrom.y);
        bounds.add(pTo.x, pTo.y);

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int) (bounds.width - bounds.x + 50), (int) (bounds.height - bounds.y + 50), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE);
        Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.translate(25.0f - bounds.getX(), 25.0f - bounds.getY());
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));


        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.drawLine(-1000, 0, 1000, 0);
        g.drawLine(0, -1000, 0, 1000);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
            if (i > 0) {
                Line2D.Float f = new Line2D.Float(points.get(i - 1).x, points.get(i - 1).y, points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y);
                System.out.println("Dist : " + f.getP1().distance(f.getP2()));
//                g.draw(f);
            }

            g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Float(points.get(i).x - 0.8f, points.get(i).y - 0.8f, 1.6f, 1.6f));

        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Float(pFrom.x - 1, pFrom.y - 1, 3, 3));
        g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Float(pTo.x - 1, pTo.y - 1, 3, 3));

        g.dispose();

        ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", new File("result.png"));
    }

    static class PointF
    {

        public float x, y;

        public PointF(float x, float y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
        }
    }

    private static List<PointF> generateCurve(PointF pFrom, PointF pTo, float pRadius, float pMinDistance, boolean shortest, boolean side)
    {

        List<PointF> pOutPut = new ArrayList<PointF>();

        // Calculate the middle of the two given points.
        PointF mPoint = new PointF(pFrom.x + pTo.x, pFrom.y + pTo.y);
        mPoint.x /= 2.0f;
        mPoint.y /= 2.0f;
        System.out.println("Middle Between From and To = " + mPoint);


        // Calculate the distance between the two points
        float xDiff = pTo.x - pFrom.x;
        float yDiff = pTo.y - pFrom.y;
        float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(xDiff * xDiff + yDiff * yDiff);
        System.out.println("Distance between From and To = " + distance);

        if (pRadius * 2.0f < distance) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The radius is too small! The given points wont fall on the circle.");
        }

        // Calculate the middle of the expected curve.
        float factor = (float) Math.sqrt((pRadius * pRadius) / ((pTo.x - pFrom.x) * (pTo.x - pFrom.x) + (pTo.y - pFrom.y) * (pTo.y - pFrom.y)) - 0.25f);
        PointF circleMiddlePoint = new PointF(0, 0);
        if (side) {
            circleMiddlePoint.x = 0.5f * (pFrom.x + pTo.x) + factor * (pTo.y - pFrom.y);
            circleMiddlePoint.y = 0.5f * (pFrom.y + pTo.y) + factor * (pFrom.x - pTo.x);
        } else {
            circleMiddlePoint.x = 0.5f * (pFrom.x + pTo.x) - factor * (pTo.y - pFrom.y);
            circleMiddlePoint.y = 0.5f * (pFrom.y + pTo.y) - factor * (pFrom.x - pTo.x);
        }
        System.out.println("Middle = " + circleMiddlePoint);

        // Calculate the two reference angles
        float angle1 = (float) Math.atan2(pFrom.y - circleMiddlePoint.y, pFrom.x - circleMiddlePoint.x);
        float angle2 = (float) Math.atan2(pTo.y - circleMiddlePoint.y, pTo.x - circleMiddlePoint.x);

        // Calculate the step.
        float step = pMinDistance / pRadius;
        System.out.println("Step = " + step);

        // Swap them if needed
        if (angle1 > angle2) {
            float temp = angle1;
            angle1 = angle2;
            angle2 = temp;

        }
        boolean flipped = false;
        if (!shortest) {
            if (angle2 - angle1 < Math.PI) {
                float temp = angle1;
                angle1 = angle2;
                angle2 = temp;
                angle2 += Math.PI * 2.0f;
                flipped = true;
            }
        }
        for (float f = angle1; f < angle2; f += step) {
            PointF p = new PointF((float) Math.cos(f) * pRadius + circleMiddlePoint.x, (float) Math.sin(f) * pRadius + circleMiddlePoint.y);
            pOutPut.add(p);
        }
        if (flipped ^ side) {
            pOutPut.add(pFrom);
        } else {
            pOutPut.add(pTo);
        }

        return pOutPut;
    }
}
```

---

and the use the generateCurve method like this to have a curve between the from and to points..

```
generateCurve(pFrom, pTo, 100f, 7f, true, false);
```

Comment: Almost. I'm getting jumpy results when I try to translate it over. It's giving me 2 points on -a- circle, but not the circle defined by the point. (I altered it a little to fit the SSCCE) I'll play with it a little more in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here it is, testing and working. The problems were based on the fact that I don't use graphics much, so I have to remind myself that the coordinate systems are backward, and on the fact that the Javadoc description of the `Arc2D` constructor is atrocious.

In addition to these, I found that your point creation (for the two points to be connected) was extremely inefficient given the requirements. I had assumed you actually had to receive two arbitrary points and *then* calculate their angles, etc., but based on what you put on Pastebin, we can define the two points however we please. This benefits us.

Anyway, here's a working version, with none of that gobbledegook from before. Simplified code is simplified:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Canvas extends JComponent {
    double circleX, circleY, x1, y1, x2, y2, dx, dy, dx2, dy2, radius, radius2;
    Random random = new Random();
    double distance;
    private static double theta1;
    private static double theta2;
    private static double theta;
    // private static double radius;
    private Point2D point1;
    private Point2D point2;
    private Point2D center;
    private static int direction;
    private static final int CW = -1;
    private static final int CCW = 1;

public Canvas() {
    /*
     * You want two random points on a circle, so let's start correctly,
     * by setting a random *radius*, and then two random *angles*.
     * 
     * This has the added benefit of giving us the angles without having to calculate them
     */

    radius = random.nextInt(175);   //your maximum radius is higher, but we only have 200 pixels in each cardinal direction
    theta1 = random.nextInt(360);   //angle to first point (absolute measurement)
    theta2 = random.nextInt(360);   //angle to second point

    //build the points
    center = new Point2D.Double(200, 200);  //your frame is actually 400 pixels on a side
    point1 = new Point2D.Double(radius * Math.cos(toRadians(theta1)) + center.getX(), center.getY() - radius * Math.sin(toRadians(theta1)));
    point2 = new Point2D.Double(radius * Math.cos(toRadians(theta2)) + center.getX(), center.getY() - radius * Math.sin(toRadians(theta2)));

    theta = Math.abs(theta1 - theta2) <= 180 ? Math.abs(theta1 - theta2) : 360 - (Math.abs(theta1 - theta2));

    if ((theta1 + theta) % 360 == theta2) {
        direction = CCW;
    } else {
        direction = CW;
    }

    System.out.println("theta1: " + theta1 + "; theta2: " + theta2 + "; theta: " + theta + "; direction: " + (direction == CCW ? "CCW" : "CW"));
    System.out.println("point1: (" + (point1.getX() - center.getX()) + ", " + (center.getY() - point1.getY()) + ")");
    System.out.println("point2: (" + (point2.getX() - center.getX()) + ", " + (center.getY() - point2.getY()) + ")");

    // Radius now equal for both points.
}

public double toRadians(double angle) {
    return angle * Math.PI / 180;
}

public double toDegrees(double angle) {
    return angle * 180 / Math.PI;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g2) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g2;
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
            BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL));

    //centerpoint should be based on the actual center point
    Arc2D.Double centerPoint = new Arc2D.Double(center.getX() - 2, center.getY() - 2, 4, 4, 0,
            360, Arc2D.OPEN);
    //likewise these points
    Arc2D.Double point11 = new Arc2D.Double(point1.getX() - 2, point1.getY() - 2, 4, 4, 0, 360,
            Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double point22 = new Arc2D.Double(point2.getX() - 2, point2.getY() - 2, 4, 4, 0, 360,
            Arc2D.OPEN);

    // 3 points drawn in black
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.draw(centerPoint);
    g.draw(point11);
    g.draw(point22);

    // Arc drawn in blue
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.draw(new Arc2D.Double(center.getX() - radius, center.getY() - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, theta1, theta * direction, Arc2D.OPEN));
}
```

}

Comment: Is it at least drawing an arc of the appropriate shape?

Comment: No. Everything is off, sometimes the arc is drawn off the screen, and upside down. I don't know why the center is off--I'm trying to figure this out. The center is a constant initialized to (150,150).

Comment: Oh! I assumed the center was at (0,0), and that the two points were relative to the center. That may be the problem. Can you at least see what I'm doing with it (and do you think I screwed up the math)?

Comment: I'm not really seeing what you're doing with it, I'll have to look deeper. The 2 points are relative to the center that they are (radius) away from the center.

Comment: Right, but say point1 is at (20,30), and center is at (30, 10). The relative position of point1 is actually (-10, 20), and my implementation assumes the relative positions are stored in the Point2D objects, and that center = (0,0). After lunch, I'll edit my response with the absolute versions.

Comment: Okay, there were several errors (silly ones, at that). I'll edit my response momentarily.

Comment: It's still off.. Your radius was off as well--you were just doing point 1, but you need abs(point1-center). I corrected your radius and distance, but the starting point for the circle is off. http://pastebin.com/xdw81C5b

Comment: The radius is correct for both points, given the center is at (0,0) and both points are on the circumference (i.e. we only need to check one of them), but I think I would have to actually build a graphics pane and draw this thing to do more. I'm pretty sure it's correct given my understanding of how the thing draws, but since I haven't actually *seen* it draw, well, I'm coding from ignorance. Time permitting, I will draw it on a graphics pane today and see what's what.

Comment: I put a pastebin link in the comment just above yours with the code put on a graphics pane. Edit: Note the code in the link has your radius calculation commented out, and uses mine instead. It is just a small Monte Carlo thing -- Click to generate a new circle.

Comment: @SaviourSelf: Fixed, tested, verified.

Comment: It looks like you're picking angles for your test case, and using them. I'm not given angles, I'm only given 2 points on a circle and it's center point. I can't use this because I'm not given the angles.

Comment: I did exactly what you requested, using exactly the same input parameters as you. Points can be defined via (x,y), or via (r, theta). Your code generated two random points via (x,y), calculated the radius of one of them, and then forced the other to have the same radius. That's both inefficient and wrong. Since your requirement was for both points to be on the circumference of a circle of random radius (within bounds), the proper way to approach this was the working example I've provided. One random radius, two random angles. You're welcome?

Comment: To clarify: The point of this problem was I was having trouble determining the angles between the 0/2PI and the location of 2 points, then determining whether the arc went clockwise / counterclockwise. I did not have these angles. Your code does give a correct arc assuming that angles were given, but does not answer the question. It randomly generates these angles, and then uses them to draw this arc. I am only given 3 points, therefore I only generated 3 points. Is my code inefficient? Yes, only because of the data I have to work with. Is my code wrong? No. I thank you for your help.

Comment: The code you provided generated two random points. The requirements imposed mean that you cannot actually *use* two random points -- at least one of the points has a constraint, in that its coordinates (whether Cartesian, as you used, or polar, as I used) are *related*. Your code was not merely inefficient, because the second point was recast based on the requirement that it have the same radius -- you ultimately abandoned the random second point. As it turns out, polar coordinates are much better suited for all of this, as I demonstrated. I guess I was really gunning for that bounty.